# What is the life span of a question on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, deleted-questions, time-limit

What is the life span of a question on SO? Or more to the point... do valid, relevant, answered, questions get deleted in a "house cleaning" effort periodically?

I didn't see any obvious answers to this looking around...

Comment: 10k+ users can see deleted posts, so *hard* deletions are rare, if they ever happen at all.

Comment: Perhaps the blog post [The Stackoverflow Question Lifecycle](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/the-stack-overflow-question-lifecycle/) is worth a read

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This valid, relevant, answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4/when-setting-a-forms-opacity-should-i-use-a-decimal-or-double) was one of the first ever on Stack Overflow, and it's still open and active.

There's occasional house cleaning of *crap*, but good, quality content is allowed to stay forever.

Comment: It should be noted that the definition of "crap" is subject to change as time goes by. A question considered great a few years ago may now be considered off-topic, or not-constructive.

Comment: @Rachel - Yeah, I was wondering what the definition of "crap" was

Answer (score 7):

Valid, relevant, answered, questions do *not* get randomly deleted.  Old, unanswered questions or those against the FAQ are subject to it, however.

Comment: and even then, hard deletion only happens after quite some time in non-exceptional cases

Comment: Old, unanswered questions only get deleted if they have a score of zero or lower or a score of 1 with a deleted owner. [Here's the specifics in detail](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/148672)